# Как сказать на компьютерном сленге?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как сказать о "таблетке", к-я должна крякнуть прогу? - она лечит программу, взламывает программу, лицензирует ее.

Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания в пред. предложении

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз "таблетка", значит "лечит". Лечит программу от жадности.

Вот пример использования из комментариев с [этой страницы](https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5373719):

> Зачем указан русский язык? Нет такого, есть английский и чешский.
>   Где таблетка? Что лечит и сам рецепт лечения почему не указан? Что делать с crack ?!!